# How Can I Highlight Rows with TH and TD Tags with Rowspan Attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a schedule page for a college tutoring center. In order to keep it a bit more readable, I am using the rowspan attribute for sessions that occur on the same date.

In some cases, I also have the same courses with multiple sessions on the same day as well. Below is a sample table:

```
<table class="schedule">
      <tr class="tableheader">
         <th scope="col">Day</th>
         <th scope="col">Courses</th>
         <th scope="col">Times</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="rowgroup" rowspan="3">Monday</th>
         <td>All CHEM</td>
         <td>10:10 a.m. - 1:00 p.m.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>CHEM 120-152</td>
         <td>4:30 p.m. - 6:30 p.m.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>All Chem</td>
         <td>7:10 p.m. - 9:00 p.m.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="rowgroup" rowspan="2">Tuesday</th>
         <td>CHEM 120-152 &amp; 272</td>
         <td>10:10 a.m. - 2:00 p.m.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>All CHEM</td>
         <td>6:10 p.m. - 9:00 p.m.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="rowgroup" rowspan="3">Wednesday</th>
         <td rowspan="2">CHEM 120-152 &amp; 272</td>
         <td>10:10 a.m. - 12:00 p.m.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>1:10 p.m. - 2:00 p.m.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>All CHEM</td>
         <td>3:10 p.m. - 6:00 p.m.</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

How would I be able to highlight an entire row including the parent elements that use rowspan using jQuery?

I found a partial solution the works generally, but when the courses column has a rowspan attribute it tends to break except on the first child. A lot of solutions I have seen do not take the TH tag into account which must be there per Section 508 which I must adhere to as much as possible.

Comment: I think by “including the parent elements that use rowspan” you actually mean “including the cells of other rows that include slots on this row”. The parent element of a `tr` element is a `tbody`, `thead`, `tfoot`, or `table` element.

Comment: Yes, so if a user hovers the mouse over the courses, the day and time, first time if the course cell has a rowspan, are highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("td[rowspan]"); // returns all elements with any rowspan property.
$("td[rowspan='3']"); // returns all elements with rowspan 3.
```

Comment: It’s `$("td[rowspan]")`, without the inner quotes.

Comment: But how would I then apply this to highlight any parent/child elements?

Comment: I tried using both .parent() and .children() but the require TR tags seem to break it.